# nx.draw_networkx shows module matplotlib has no attribute path

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to learn some Python graph visualization. while running the following piece of code I am encountering this error

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'path'

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
FG = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(pandas_df)
nx.draw_networkx(FG, with_labels=True)
```

Any help would be appereciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason after I close and reopen the spyder it worked.